# Data encryption within a stored procedure

Tags: sql, encryption, sql-server-2008-r2

I am playing around with this right now to learn so I can eventually apply it to some work that I am doing.  This is on SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a table that I am inserting to. Call it `TestTable` with 1 column `Col1 varbinary(256)`

So creating a stored procedure.

```
create procedure [dbo].[p_TestEncrypt] @number as varchar(50)
as
   OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY TestTableKey DECRYPTION
   BY CERTIFICATE TestTableCert

   insert into dbo.TestTable
      select ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('TestTableKey'), @number)
```

So..  If I do an

```
execute dbo.p_TestEncrypt '123456'
```

It runs fine however when I run the decrypt code I am getting:  1

But if I run it like this

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY TestTableKey DECRYPTION
BY CERTIFICATE TestTableCert

insert into dbo.TestTable
select ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('TestTableKey'), '123456')
```

When I run the decrypt code I am getting: 123456

I am not sure why..  Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! That way, you don't need any of those messy `<br/>` tags, either!

Comment: The first thing to look for when strings are being truncated to a single character is for any instances of `varchar` where a length isn't specified. Obviously, the parameter to `p_TestEncrypt` has a length (50) specified, but look to see if there's any other code involved that doesn't have the length.

Comment: I know I have seen this before when I would leave the length off..  But it is specified here which is what has me a bit baffled.

Comment: So I added a second column that is a varchar(50) and posted the same variable @number to it also.  The unencrypted varchar(50) field posted all of the data while the encrypted one is only posting the first character still.  Strange.

Comment: Ok. I found the issue.  It was not in this code.  It ended up being on the decrypt side I was converting it to a varchar(50), with the string being all numbers it was only showing the 1st character.  I changed the conversion to nvarchar(50) and it worked.